# Google Chrome Extension onSingInChanged always returns signedIn = true

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Why https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#event-onSignInChanged method onSignInChanged returns account data and signedIn = true, no matter if I log in or log out of my google account. Triggering of this event is correct - it triggers when i Sign In and Sign Out, but returns the same data with both actions